# How to combine object hierarchy meshes as a single one

Tags: modeling, mesh, unity

I'm trying to export my model to Unity as a single object.

However I'm having a big trouble combining all gameobject children meshes as one. This is the hierarchy I get in Unity:

[image]

### What I want to achieve

Within Unity, the hierarchy is completely useless to me. I want to have a single model, without any children meshes. In sum, all combined into one, just "object":

[image]

### I already tried

- I tried using a Combine Meshes script within Unity, however unsuccessful.
- I tried to change the export settings in Blender, but I'm unable to get it as a single object!
- I tried joining all the meshes (CTRL J) but I can never get a single object.

How can I achieve this?

Best Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. I think it would be helpful if you describe better what you did with ctrl+j command. What exactly failed? Are all the objects mesh type or other (curves, text,..)?

Comment: I'm unable to use the Join (CTRL+J) because it's blocked, probably something related with the mesh type. When I join one of the child instances, I get "No mesh data to join".

Comment: *"When I join one of the child instances, I get "No mesh data to join""* that has to be in the question body as this is important part. This means that either you have no active object of mesh type (selected last) or one of the objects you're trying to join isn't of the mesh type at all (lamp, curve etc)

Comment: I suspected that was the problem. I'm not sure how I did it, I was probably over selecting, but I managed to get it fixed. I selected all groups using 'A' (instead of SHIFT+LMB) and converted everything into a single unit using Join option (Object -> Join). Thank you Carlo and Mr Zak.

Comment: The only difference right now is the file-size (from 2MB to 14MB).